# A weird NullPointerException in compilation Java 8 (compiler (1.8.0_31))

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I'm trying to compile my code in this environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T19:29:23+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/sbin/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/sbin/jdk1.8.0_31/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-23-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown from `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isConvertible()`

I've seen that this exception is reported as a bug, but I couldn't find what should be done to avoid it (perhaps use other version of java or maven?)

Anybody has a clue?

This is the stacktrace:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ tnet ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1358 source files to /tradair/sources/java/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_31). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isConvertible(Types.java:290)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.assertConvertible(Check.java:922)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkMethod(Check.java:876)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethod(Attr.java:3838)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkIdInternal(Attr.java:3615)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodIdInternal(Attr.java:3522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodId(Attr.java:3501)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkId(Attr.java:3488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1843)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitReturn(Attr.java:1704)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCReturn.accept(JCTree.java:1384)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:692)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Attr.java:1142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4342)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4252)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4181)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4156)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:684)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.622 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-29T10:51:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/509M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project tnet: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: 1)  Look to see if someone else has filed a bug.  2) If not, file a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044546) in an old version of OpenJDK. You should try updating to at least 8u40 as it is apparently resolved there.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058283) which is marked as unresolved.  (But this could be the same bug that Quirliom found in the OpenJDK tracker ... and "Bugs Database" folks haven't noticed that there is duplication.)

Answer (score 0):

As Quirliom says, it is a bad bug in the compiler.  If you can find the offending code you can work around it by assigning the lambda to a variable.  FunctionalJava has run into this several times (e.g. https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/issues/76).  We worked around problem code like this:

`return foldLeft((i, a) -> i + 1, 0);`

by assigning to a variable:

`F2<Integer, A, Integer> f = (i, a) -> i + 1;
return foldLeft(f, 0);`